# Is there a way to have an upload image as the button in uploadifive?

Tags: uploadify, uploadifive

I know there is buttonClass but that doesn't allow images to be displayed? Basically I want to use an image as the button instead of what is generated using the buttonText. I know in uploadity there is a buttonImg attribute. I was wondering if there is anything that can do the same thing in uploadifive?

Answer (score 0):

In the *uploadifive.css* file you need to edit the *uploadify-button* class with the following attributes:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url('path/to/your/image');
```

or you could define your own buttonClass and reference that.